# Show that this definite integral is equal to 1/2

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate $\int_0^{L/2}\phi^2(x)\,dx$, where $\phi(x) = (\frac{2}{L})^{1/2}*\sin(\frac{nx\pi}{L})$, where $L$ is a constant, and $n$ is a positive integer ($\phi$ is the wavefunction for a particle in a box of length $L$ with quantum number $n$).

The answer is $\frac{1}{2}$, because the probability of finding the particle on the left side of the box (from $0$ to $\frac{L}{2}$) is $\frac{1}{2}$.

However, I'm having difficulty getting $\frac{1}{2}$. Here is my work:

$\int_0^{L/2}\phi^2(x)\,dx = $ $\frac{2}{L}*\int_0^{L/2}\sin^2(\frac{n*\pi*x}{L})\,dx = $ $\frac{1}{L}*(\frac{L}{2} - \int_0^{L/2}\cos(\frac{n*\pi*x}{L})\,dx) = $ $\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{L}*\frac{\sin(\frac{n*\pi*x}{L})}{\frac{n*\pi*x}{L}} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sin(\frac{n*\pi*x}{L})}{2*n*\pi}$. I'm not sure how to show that this expression is equal to 1.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: You did not use the bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there

You have that 
$$\sin^2 x= \frac 12(1-\color{red}{\cos(2x)})$$
$$I=\frac{1}{L}\left(\frac{L}{2} - \int_0^{L/2}\cos(\frac{2n \pi x}{L})\,dx \right) $$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} - \frac 1L\int_0^{L/2}\cos(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})\,dx $$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} - \frac 1L \left |\frac{L}{2n\pi } \sin(\frac{2n\pi*x}{L}) \right |_0^{L/2} $$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} -\left |\frac{\sin(\frac{2n\pi x}{L})}{2n\pi }  \right |_0^{L/2} $$
$$I=\frac{1}{2} -\frac{(\sin(n\pi)-\sin(0))}{2n\pi }  $$
$$I=\frac{1}{2}$$